# Parsing lines into a variable for later use

Tags: powershell

I'm a newb w/ Powershell and I am trying to perform similar operations I did previously in bash in PS.  I'm working w/ a "driver" file of 25+ Snowflake accounts.  Each line in the driver file holds key info about a Snowflake account, delimited by ',', w/ field 5 (or 4 starting from 0) being the account's URL.

My goal is to parse the file, grab field 5 and modify it a bit, storing all lines in a variable.  The variable would be used dynamically for various ad-hoc duties.

I'm trying:

```
$ALLACCTS=(foreach ($LINE in Get-Content -Path "snowflake_acct_driver.txt" | Select-String -Pattern '^#' -notmatch) {((($LINE -split ',')[4]) -Replace 'https://', '') -Replace '\.snowflakecomputing\.com', ''})
```

and getting errors like:

> At line:1 char:24
> $STUFF=(foreach ($LINE in Get-Content -Path "$HHOME\data\snowflake_ac ...
> +...

The `foreach` command works fine on its own, without being part of a variable assignment and no surrounding parenthesis.  Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement as part of a *larger expression*, replace `(...)` with `$(...)`

That is, instead of:

```bash
$ALLACCTS = (foreach ...) -replace ...
```

use:

```bash
$ALLACCTS = $(foreach ...) -replace ...
```

---

Perhaps surprisingly, *language statements* such as `foreach`, `while`, `switch`, `do`, and `if`:

- *can* be used *as-is, in isolation* as expressions in *assignment statements* (`$var = <statement>`)
- can *not* be used *as part of a larger expression* via [`(...)`, the grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) or *at the start of a pipeline* (`<statement> | ...`)

  - However, you *can* use them as such via `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), or `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--).

See [GitHub issue #6817](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817) for a discussion.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thx for help on my PS learning journey.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Dave; my pleasure.